# Rescanning a increased root partition size Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, root

Ubuntu 20.0.04 LTS

I used Clonezilla to clone my Linux installation and move it over to a SSD for now until my new USB stick comes in.  I used the expert config, and -k1 option to make use of the available space.  Which as I can view in Gparted/Disks looks like it worked, filesystem/extended is 494GB now rather than 14GB as it was before without that option.

I'm still getting low disk space warnings and am unsure whether or not what I did worked and its just a visual error or not.

When I view other locations its still showing 250MB/14.5GB available, I've done a scsi rescan but that didn't help and I've been unable to find what command I'd need to update this.

[Disks view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqo8r.jpg)

Comment: Was the original usb formatted a ext4? Clearly the -k1 option has not worked well. Why not restore it again without the -k1 and then use GParted in a live environment to resize the partition manually

Comment: alright will try that thanks, to do that I just need to do a clone, and resize the partition that would be normally mounted to root right?

Comment: Yes that’s correct